# ionic 4 ion-select-option text wrap

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm unable to wrap the text in my ion-select-option.

```html
  <ion-list>
    <ion-list-header>Select one of your work orders</ion-list-header>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-select [(ngModel)]="selection" (ionChange)="optionsFn(selection)">
        <ion-select-option [value]="work" *ngFor="let order of workOrder">{{order.destination}} - {{order.startDate | date: "MM/dd/yyyy"}} - {{order.endDate | date: "MM/dd/yyyy"}}</ion-select-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

I actually saw a solution using the following CSS

```css
.alert-radio-label.sc-ion-alert-ios {
    padding-left: unset;
    padding-right: unset;
    -webkit-padding-start: 13px;
    padding-inline-start: 13px;
    -webkit-padding-end: 13px;
    padding-inline-end: 13px;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

If I add white-space: pre-wrap; in the console debugger the text from the ion-select will wrap successfully with the following:

[image]

The problem is if I add that to the css it doesn't take effect.  So I'm not sure where it should be added.  In another post someone suggested adding it to the app.css but I don't have a global app.css in my ionic 4 project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the alert html is outside of your component, you need to add it to the global CSS of your app... in Ionic 4 generated project you have global.scss that you can use for it, if you can't find it or it doesn't work... use the variables.scss, although I think you can just use global.scss.

Comment: so that works for the alert.  It doesn't work for <div> in a shadow root.

Comment: It all depends where the div is... If it's in your component then just add the CSS to your component's SCSS file

Comment: You know...after implementing this in the variables.scss it worked only in the console.  When I deploy to an actual device it won't work.  I'm thinking it may be a bug in Ionic

Comment: No, usually it's either a specific browser you're dealing with on your mobile phone... maybe an old one that needs some -webkit prefix or something... just find what is exactly not working and fix that.